# Flutter simulate an action on the navigation bar with provider

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I work with provider and I am a little confused with a problem. I want to simulate an action on the navigation bar when I click a button on the page.

**Example**:

*My navigation bar consists of 3 items (menu 1, menu 2, menu 3). By clicking on the "Go to menu 2" button on my page, I want to make it look like I was clicking on the navigation bar. So the page changes and the navigation bar is updated.
In my example I will work with 3 pages to make it easier to understand. **InitialElementScreen**, **InitialElementResultScreen**, **CorrectionsScreen**.
The **InitialElementResultScreen** has no navigation bar.*

**My problem**:

For that I use provider. I manage to do my system when I am on a menu page. Example if I put my button on the **InitialElementScreen** page then my system will work and take me to **CorrectionsScreen**.
It no longer works if my button is on the **InitialElementResultScreen** page which is a page opened with navigator.push from **InitialElementScreen**.

Here is my tree structure when I am on **InitialElementScreen**:

[image]

My AppScreen:

```
class AppScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ChangeNotifierProvider<LicenseNotifier>(
      create: (_) => LicenseNotifier(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: AppConfig.APPLICATION_NAME,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: AppTheme().data,
        initialRoute: AppRoutes.HOME,
        onGenerateRoute: RoutesClass.generate,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My RouteClass :

```
abstract class RoutesClass{

  static Route<dynamic> generate(RouteSettings settings){
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch(settings.name){
      case AppRoutes.HOME :
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Consumer(
            builder: (context, LicenseNotifier license, _) {
              return license.selectHomeScreen();
            },
          ),
        );
      break;
}
```

My Widget selectHomeScreen in my LicenseNotifier:

```
Widget selectHomeScreen()
  {
    switch (appState) {
      case AppState.Uninitialized:
        return SplashedScreen();
        break;
      case AppState.Authenticating:
      case AppState.Unauthenticated:
        return LicenseHomeScreen(title: "Activate the license");
        break;
      case AppState.Authenticated:
        return ChangeNotifierProvider<BottomNavigationBarNotifier>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => BottomNavigationBarNotifier(),
          child: NavigationBarScreen(),
        );
        break;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

My NavigationBarScreen :

```
class NavigationBarScreen extends StatelessWidget
{
  NavigationBarScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var navigationProvider = Provider.of<BottomNavigationBarNotifier>(context);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: navigationProvider.loadScreenWithNavigation(),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: navigationProvider.currentIndex,
          onTap: (index) {
            navigationProvider.navigationScreenIndex = index;
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Menu 1',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.calculate),
              label: 'Menu 2',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.library_books_sharp),
              label: 'Menu 3',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My BottomNavigationBarNotifier:

```
class BottomNavigationBarNotifier with ChangeNotifier {

  int currentIndex = AppConfig.NAVIGATION_DEFAULT_INDEX;
  BottomNavigationBarNotifier();

  set navigationScreenIndex(int index) {
    currentIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Widget loadScreenWithNavigation()
  {
    switch (currentIndex)
    {
      case 0:
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
           ... some providers
          ],
          child: InitialElementScreen(title : 'Menu 1'),
        );
        break;

      case 1:
        return CorrectionsScreen(title: 'Menu 2')
        break;

      case 2:
        return TableHomeScreen(title: 'Menu 3');
        break;

      default:
        return InitialElementScreen(title : 'Menu 1');
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

So if the button "Go to Menu 2" is in my **InitialElementScreen**, it's works. The code of the button:

```
var _formProvider = Provider.of<BottomNavigationBarNotifier>(context, listen: false);
    _formProvider.navigationScreenIndex = 1;
    notifyListeners();
```

Now I want my "Go to Menu 2" button to be in a sub page of menu 1, so I'm going to have a button in my **InitialElementScreen** to open my **InitialElementResultScreen** page:

```
await Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppRoutes.RESULT, arguments: jsonEncode(data.toMap()));
```

Now still in my RouteClass file, I add this code to load my **InitialElementResultScreen** page:

```
case AppRoutes.RESULT:
        var data = settings.arguments as String;
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Consumer(
            builder: (context, LicenseNotifier license, _) {
              return ChangeNotifierProvider<BottomNavigationBarNotifier>(
                create: (BuildContext context) => BottomNavigationBarNotifier(),
                child: ChangeNotifierProvider<InitialCalculatorResultNotifier>(
                  create: (BuildContext context) => InitialCalculatorResultNotifier(),
                  child: InitialElementResultScreen(title: "Sub Menu 1", data: data),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
        break;
```

Here is now my tree structure when I am on my sub page of menu 1, **InitialElementResultScreen**:
[image]

If I put my "Go to Menu 2" button back in the **InitialElementResultScreen** page, it doesn't work anymore ... I come back to the Menu 1 page, **InitialElementScreen**, why ?

Code of my button "Go to Menu 2"
which is the same as shown above with a Navigator.pop:

```
var _formProvider = Provider.of<BottomNavigationBarNotifier>(context, listen: false);
    _formProvider.navigationScreenIndex = 1;
    notifyListeners();
    Navigator.pop(context);
```

**EDIT: I resolve my problem !
From what I understand the secondary page opened with navigator.push opens under the MaterialApp Widget. So I moved my BottomNavigationBarNotifier above.**

```
class AppScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ChangeNotifierProvider<LicenseNotifier>(
      create: (_) => LicenseNotifier(),
      child: ChangeNotifierProvider<BottomNavigationBarNotifier>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => BottomNavigationBarNotifier(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: AppConfig.APPLICATION_NAME,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: AppTheme().data,
          initialRoute: AppRoutes.HOME,
          onGenerateRoute: RoutesClass.generate,
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```